# Meaning of "I have a son that age"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Today i was watching a movie with subtitle and I found a sentence that is " I have a son that age ". Now I dont know if the sub maker made some mistake or not. I think it should be " I have a son of that age". Please tell me If I am correct or not.

Comment: you are correct, but it is spoken language, so not formal.

Comment: If that's what the character in the movie said, then the subtitle is correct. But often, subtitles simplify what was said. Anyway, the character in the movie is not obliged to speak correct English.

Comment: Dropping the *of* is a common trope and sometimes more popular. Why do you think it's a mistake?

Comment: "A son that age" is fine, in fact I suspect it is used slightly more than "a son of that age". Both the NP "that age" and the PP "of that age" modify "son".

Comment: It must be a great shock to ESL learners to discover that native speakers (very) often don't speak like grammar books. Like it was for me with French when I went to live there.

Comment: Thank you everyone , now I get that. As English is my second language, I dont understand that kind of English much.

Answer (score 1):

It must be a great shock to ESL learners to discover that native speakers (very) often don't speak like grammar books. "A son that age" is fine, in fact I suspect it is used slightly more than "a son of that age". Both the noun phrase "that age" and the prepositional phrase "of that age" modify "son"